# How to remove spacing between <picture> tags?

Tags: html, css

I have managed to display 3 images one after the other in mobile preview through the following HTML code:

```html
<main>

  <div class="showcase">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width:1100px)" srcset="images/p1.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width:900px)" srcset="images/p1tab.jpg">

          <img src="images/p1mob.jpg" width=100% alt="Image 1" />
    </picture>

    <p> <a href="">OUR MENU</a> 
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="showcase">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width:1100px)" srcset="images/p2.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width:900px)" srcset="images/p2tab.jpg">

          <img src="images/p2mob.jpg" width=100% alt="Image 2" />
    </picture>
    <p><a href="">RESERVATIONS</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="showcase">
    <picture>
      <source media="(min-width:1100px)" srcset="images/p3.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width:900px)" srcset="images/p3tab.jpg">

          <img src="images/p3mob.jpg" width=100% alt="Image 3" />
    </picture>
    <p> <a href="">LOCATE US </a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="horizontal">
    <a href=""> ORDER ONLINE </a>
  </div>
</main>
```

I have used the following CSS for formatting:

```css
main {
  margin: 0px;
}
.showcase {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.showcase picture {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.showcase p a {
  margin: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 44%;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Fjalla One;
  color: white;
  /* TRBL */
}
```

I tried to take away margins everywhere but still, somehow the margins underneath the picture would NEVER go away.

Here is how to is being displayed:

[image]

I don't want the gap to be visible. Where am I missing out on the code? The spacing always appears UNDER the photo, not above the three images.

Comment: Can you add code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I am not aware of jsfiddle. What is that?

Comment: [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/) provides a custom environment to test your JavaScript, HTML, and CSS code right inside your browser.

Comment: Okay I'll post the code in jsfiddle once I get back on my pc and post it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yv1awjvv/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have position:absolute on the `<a>` tag, so the `<p>` tag is still sitting down below the image. Even though it has no height, it probably still has margins, which are causing the gaps.  I think you can apply the positioning css to the p tags or set their margins to 0 to fix. (minor edit because i realized you had style rules for how the anchor is displayed)

Edit: 
Also note that there will still be some space between them because images are inline by default and placed on the baseline.  You can fix that by either setting the `<img>s` to `display:block` or `vertical-align:bottom`.

Comment: Adding no margins to the <p> tag seem to have fixed the issue a lot but yes, as you said, there is still some space between the images. I tried to fix it using display:block and vertical-align:bottom but nothing seemed to work. Why is that? I added them in the .showcase picture.

Comment: I figured out my mistake, this worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `display:block` attribute to all the images.

Create a new `css` class:

```
.showcase picture img{
     display:block
}
```

Ref: [Space between div and img?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947113/space-between-div-and-img)